# Reactjs: Complex Nested forms and managing State

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS and MUI components to create a dynamic form based on the following JSON.

```
{
"form": {
    "groups": [{
        "group_id": "acfcbaa6-3bb9-45c0-ad0a-cb5237359bbb",
        "group_name": "Group 1",
        "elements": [{
                "element_id": "dfc81836-3bb9-45c0-ad0a-cb5237359ba9",
                "element_name": "report_type_id",
                "element_type": "S",
                "label": "Select a product",
                "required": false,
                "display": true,
                "options": [{
                        "option_id": "0479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6a1",
                        "option_name": "Product 1",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "0479f5f1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6a8",
                        "option_name": "Product 2",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "0479sda1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6a0",
                        "option_name": "Product 3",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "0479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6bb",
                        "option_name": "Product 4",
                        "elements": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "element_id": "05bea614-6dc6-4c89-99db-fa6fa791728b",
                "element_name": "product_price",
                "element_type": "T",
                "label": "Product Price",
                "required": false,
                "display": true,
                "options": []
            },
            {
                "element_id": "05bea614-6dc6-4c89-99db-fa6fa791728b",
                "element_name": "product_category",
                "element_type": "S",
                "label": "Product Category",
                "required": false,
                "display": true,
                "options": [{
                        "option_id": "b479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1cca5572a6a1",
                        "option_name": "Product Cat 1",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "b479f5f1-fd8f-487e-6f46-1f3a5572a6a8",
                        "option_name": "Product Cat 2",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "0549sda1-fd8f-487e-4d46-1f3a5572a6a0",
                        "option_name": "Product Cat 3",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "a479fcb1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6bb",
                        "option_name": "Product Cat 4",
                        "elements": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "element_id": "05bea614-6dc6-4c89-99db-fa6fa791728b",
                "element_name": "payment_method",
                "element_type": "S",
                "label": "Payment Method",
                "required": false,
                "display": true,
                "options": [{
                        "option_id": "b479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1cca5572a6a1",
                        "option_name": "Cash",
                        "elements": []
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "0549sda1-fd8f-487e-4d46-1f3a5572a6a0",
                        "option_name": "Credit Card",
                        "elements": [{
                                "element_id": "4745aca7-beb6-4892-9f68-05b1609e56d9",
                                "element_name": "credit_card",
                                "element_type": "CC",
                                "label": "Credit Card"
                            },
                            {
                                "element_id": "42159553-f2c3-4bab-978c-6ac76e65989b",
                                "element_name": "cc_exp_month",
                                "element_type": "T",
                                "label": "Expiration Month"
                            },
                            {
                                "element_id": "9b693880-210b-4946-bf9c-da99a44b3fb6",
                                "element_name": "cc_exp_year",
                                "element_type": "T",
                                "label": "Expiration Year"
                            },
                            {
                                "element_id": "14c7b16d-5595-42fb-ba75-6517ffbd0cdc",
                                "element_name": "cc_code",
                                "element_type": "T",
                                "label": "Code"
                            },
                            {
                                "element_id": "56f6ebf7-4dc0-4609-a2fc-dc7d19859e69",
                                "element_name": "billing_first_name",
                                "element_type": "T",
                                "label": "Billing First Name"
                            },
                            {
                                "element_id": "1f084d95-be3d-4bba-814b-83a51f27e0df",
                                "element_name": "billing_last_name",
                                "element_type": "T",
                                "label": "Billing Last Name"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}}
```

As you can see, this json has nested structure and there is no limit to how deep the nesting can go. So we have a complex and nested form. The question is - how do we maintain a single form document which gets updated when the form element's value changes.I used useState hook and maintained a state object at the top level and have passed the nested values back to the parent form using callbacks (a deep callback chain is formed but gets the work done). However, every time a single value change, the entire form is rendered which isn't very optimal. Can anyone suggest a better solution? How would an expert React developer handle such a use-case?

Comment: I assume that you have a controlled input component, and the form has many input components, and you only have a state object that carries the state for your whole form, the ideal way to prevent unnecessary computations is to wrap your input component with a React.memo.

Comment: "every time a single value change, the entire form is rendered" - This is the way React is intended to work. When a parent component renders it renders its ***entire*** sub-ReactTree. Wrap the components in the sub-ReactTree with the `React.memp` HOC to help indicate/hint to React that a component rerender ***to the DOM*** may not be necessary since passed prop values haven't changed. You've only shared your data, but if you share how you are rendering a form and fields we can probably make better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to remap the current form template into the format of existing view engine. For example, you could try [jsonforms](https://jsonforms.io/docs/integrations/react) or [react-declaravie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-declarative)

> Demo app is available [on this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-declarative-template-mapping-dfgbup?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { One, FieldType } from "react-declarative";

const template = {
  form: {
    groups: [
      {
        group_id: "acfcbaa6-3bb9-45c0-ad0a-cb5237359bbb",
        group_name: "Group 1",
        elements: [
          {
            element_id: "dfc81836-3bb9-45c0-ad0a-cb5237359ba9",
            element_name: "report_type_id",
            element_type: "S",
            label: "Select a product",
            required: false,
            display: true,
            options: [
              {
                option_id: "0479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6a1",
                option_name: "Product 1",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "0479f5f1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6a8",
                option_name: "Product 2",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "0479sda1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6a0",
                option_name: "Product 3",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "0479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6bb",
                option_name: "Product 4",
                elements: []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            element_id: "05bea614-6dc6-4c89-99db-fa6fa791728b",
            element_name: "product_price",
            element_type: "T",
            label: "Product Price",
            required: false,
            display: true,
            options: []
          },
          {
            element_id: "05bea614-6dc6-4c89-99db-fa6fa791728b",
            element_name: "product_category",
            element_type: "S",
            label: "Product Category",
            required: false,
            display: true,
            options: [
              {
                option_id: "b479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1cca5572a6a1",
                option_name: "Product Cat 1",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "b479f5f1-fd8f-487e-6f46-1f3a5572a6a8",
                option_name: "Product Cat 2",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "0549sda1-fd8f-487e-4d46-1f3a5572a6a0",
                option_name: "Product Cat 3",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "a479fcb1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1f3a5572a6bb",
                option_name: "Product Cat 4",
                elements: []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            element_id: "05bea614-6dc6-4c89-99db-fa6fa791728b",
            element_name: "payment_method",
            element_type: "S",
            label: "Payment Method",
            required: false,
            display: true,
            options: [
              {
                option_id: "b479f2a1-fd8f-487e-8d46-1cca5572a6a1",
                option_name: "Cash",
                elements: []
              },
              {
                option_id: "0549sda1-fd8f-487e-4d46-1f3a5572a6a0",
                option_name: "Credit Card",
                elements: [
                  {
                    element_id: "4745aca7-beb6-4892-9f68-05b1609e56d9",
                    element_name: "credit_card",
                    element_type: "CC",
                    label: "Credit Card"
                  },
                  {
                    element_id: "42159553-f2c3-4bab-978c-6ac76e65989b",
                    element_name: "cc_exp_month",
                    element_type: "T",
                    label: "Expiration Month"
                  },
                  {
                    element_id: "9b693880-210b-4946-bf9c-da99a44b3fb6",
                    element_name: "cc_exp_year",
                    element_type: "T",
                    label: "Expiration Year"
                  },
                  {
                    element_id: "14c7b16d-5595-42fb-ba75-6517ffbd0cdc",
                    element_name: "cc_code",
                    element_type: "T",
                    label: "Code"
                  },
                  {
                    element_id: "56f6ebf7-4dc0-4609-a2fc-dc7d19859e69",
                    element_name: "billing_first_name",
                    element_type: "T",
                    label: "Billing First Name"
                  },
                  {
                    element_id: "1f084d95-be3d-4bba-814b-83a51f27e0df",
                    element_name: "billing_last_name",
                    element_type: "T",
                    label: "Billing Last Name"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};

const fields = template.form.groups
  .map(({ group_name, elements }) => [
    {
      type: FieldType.Line,
      title: group_name
    },
    ...elements.map(({
      element_name,
      element_type,
      options,
      label
    }) => ({
      type: element_type === "S"
        ? FieldType.Combo
        : FieldType.Text,
      name: element_name,
      itemList: options.map(({
        option_name
      }) => option_name),
      title: label
    }))
  ])
  .flat();

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (data) => setData(data);

  return (
    <>
      <One fields={fields} onChange={handleChange} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]